# L'origine du mot canette (de bière)

Tags: étymologie

Je me posais la question de savoir si le mot **canette** venait ou pas d'un néologisme créé lors de l'apparition de ce genre de récipient en Europe…

D'après mon père, il s'agit d'une des choses qui sont apparues après la 2<sup>e</sup> guerre, en provenance des États-Unis. Il parait, à ce sujet, que les gens, ici en Belgique du moins, s'étaient moqués de cette *invention*, prétendant que « Jamais personne ne serait tenté de boire dans des boites de conserve ! »

Bref, ma question est donc : est-ce que *canette* vient de l'anglais « canned » qui était (et est toujours) imprimé sur certaines boites (comme « Canned in Colorado ») ?

Comment: "Canette" in *can* in English. Still very plasible there is some connection :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

D'après le [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/canette), il semblerait que l'origine soit plutôt allemande (et beaucoup plus ancienne que la 2ème guerre) :

> Origine germanique, cane (« cruche ») est attesté en ancien français
>   (voir can en anglais, Kanne en allemand). De cette racine est dérivé
>   canon dans l’expression boire un canon.

Confirmé par [Le Littré](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=canette&dicoid=LITTRE1872) :

> **CANETTE** (ka-nè-t')
>
> 1. Mesure de liquide restée en usage dans les débits de bière et qui est un vase ayant un bec, ou une bouteille de forme particulière
>      tenant un litre. 
>      Le contenu. Boire une canette.
>
> **HISTORIQUE**
>
> XIIe s.
>    Rois, 317: Tost après commanda que l'om quatre chanes de eve emplist
>    XVIe s.
>     CALVIN, Instit. 881: Fondre un seul calice, ou rompre une petite cannette 
>     d'argent
>     MARG. DE NAV., Nouv. XIX: Portant les deux cannettes en ses deux mains, 
>     couvertes d'une toile de soie…
>     D'AUB., Conf. I, 2: Mesme un jour comme il tenoit le calice et l'autre les 
>     cannettes, il s'escria…
>
> **ÉTYMOLOGIE**
>
> Norm. canne, cruche ; wallon, canète ; du bas-latin canna, kanna, de canna, canne, plusieurs vases ayant, à cause de leur forme, reçu ce
>   nom.

Answer (score 5):

La réponse de Cédric Julien est confirmée par le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (sld Alain Rey) et l'*OED*. Les deux mots, anglais *can* et français *canette* (qui peut s'écrire aussi *cannette*) sont issus d'une même origine germanique (elle-même issue d'une racine latine) et les deux mots étaient déjà employés en vieil anglais et en ancien français dans le sens de **vase**, **récipient contenant un liquide**.

*Canette de bière* est attesté pour la première fois en 1856, comme une petite bouteille de bière de contenance de 25 à 33 centilitres.