# Terme inconnu : « bambou canon »

Tags: vocabulaire, argot, jargon

Dans une vidéo, juste après le point [19m56s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLZBfrqA9HY&19m56s) on peut entendre le terme « bambou canon ». On trouve bien la référence suivante : [Bamboo cannon](https://tr-ex.me/traduction/anglais-fran%C3%A7ais/bamboo+cannon#gref). Ces définitions ne sont pas ce qui convient. Que signifie ce terme qui semble être de l'argot ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il dit ***boire mon canon***, c'est à dire, boire mon verre de vin (à chaque repas).

Voir aussi : [What does prendre un canon mean?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49452/what-does-prendre-un-canon-mean) et [Origine du mot canette](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1812/lorigine-du-mot-canette-de-bi%c3%a8re)

Comment: It's funny how they have 30 translations available for the closed captions, and all of them are equally wrong beginning from the French transcriptionist's misconception. A good example of how 60 million Germans can be wrong, etc. etc.

Comment: @LukeSawczak A good example of alcoholism-induced diction impairment too.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Vu le passé de SDF de ce Dieudonné, il est possible que les repas aient été exclusivement constitués de vin rouge...

Comment: Réf. l'alcool avec les repas ; probablement en effet. Vu mon interprétation initiale et ce vers quoi elle tendait, j'ai grandement limité l'écoute...